# Android WebView doesn't play Youtube video while clicked

Tags: android, android-webview

I know this question is asked so many times but none of the solution worked for.What I am trying to do is very simple.I hava a url and I want to load that url in a `WebView`.That url contains videos.Bt while clicking on the play button, it does not play anything.

Following is my code that I have tried so far,

```
public class MoviesActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Adds Progrss bar Support
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(  Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 

        // Get Web view
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1); //This is the id you gave 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        }

             //to the WebView in the main.xml
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);         //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this 
      //  mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);                                                    //if ROM supports Multi-Touch      
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM
        // Load URL



        // Sets the Chrome Client, and defines the onProgressChanged
        // This makes the Progress bar be updated.
        final Activity MyActivity = this;
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        {
            //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

            // Return the app name after finish loading
            if(progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
          }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/user/africanmoviesnews");  
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 
    }//End of Method onCreate
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it works for me.

```
WebView video = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.video);
String widthAndHeight = "width='220' height='200'";
String videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/DZi6DEJsOJ0?fs=1&amp;hl=nl_NL";

String temp = "<object "+widthAndHeight+">" +
"<param name='allowFullScreen' value='false'>" +
"</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>" +
"</param><embed src='"+ videoURL +"'" +
" type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'" + widthAndHeight +
"></embed></object>";

video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
video.loadData(temp,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ram. But I have a to load a website url not a single video.Check this url "http://www.youtube.com/user/africanmoviesnews". Hope I am clear.